# Finding Cell Range With Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I have an many embedded objects (shapes) in a worksheet and the icons is displayed inside a cell. How do I know the Cell range in which the shape object is displayed.

*Example:* When I select a `B2` and then select the object(shape) in the  `B17`, and I query on the `Cell.Address` it shows `B2` - how do I get the cell address as `B17`?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Shape` properties `.TopLeftCell` and `.BottomRightCell` to return the extents of the rectangular range that the shape overlaps.

In your example, `YourShape.TopLeftCell.Address` should return `$B$17`